Difference between ulimit -a and /proc/$PID/limits
In Linux, there are user limits for accessing system resources.
Shell built-in command ulimit can be used to see user limits for the current user.
ulimit -a       # soft limits
ulimit -a -H    # hard limits

Then I also can see per process soft/hard limit by looking at /proc/$PID/limits.
# For example, the limits on firefox process:
PID=$(ps -A | grep firefox | awk '{print $1;}' | head -n1)
cat /proc/$PID/limits

# OR in short:
cat /proc/$(ps -A | grep firefox | awk '{print $1;}' | head -n1)/limits

I am wondering what is the difference between these two output?
I see /proc/$PID/limits having some limits larger than ulimit -a -H (Hard limits) output for the same resource.
Can process spawned by a user have its limits exceed user limits (ulimit)?

I tried to include my question in a question with similar goals: https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/470961 . The edit was rejected.

As long as you are looking for the limits on the PID of your current shell, they are the same as shown in output by ulimit.
ulimit is an internal command to the current shell. See bash manual (man bash) for details. The command sets the limits for the shell and the processes spawned by it. The limits listed with the -S and -H options are the same that can be outputted with the commands:
# this command is run in the shell's process
while read l;do echo "$l";done </proc/self/limits

or
# this command is spawned into a new process. $$ expands to PID of the current shell in bash & zsh
cat /proc/$$/limits

If you look at limits on a random process like 'firefox', it may not have been spawned by the current shell.

Limits set by an ordinary user can only be raised once and then only to any value up to and including the hard limit. After that initial setting of a limit, the limit can only be lowered.
User root does not have such limitation.
Every user can have different limits. The limits are configured in the file /etc/security/limits.conf and are applied by the PAM module pam_limits.so during login.

Thanks. I assume limits for firefox process are inherited from user limits. I don't have this /etc/security/limits.conf file on my system. Anywhere else the user limits these could be defined?

When using systemd things are probably different, see this question for some information. Since I haven't switched to systemd myself I really don't know any specifics.

By the way cat /proc/$$/limits may spawn a new cat process, but $$ expands before that, and would point to the PID of shell process, not cat child process.

So, cat /proc/self/limits is what you meant I believe. This can be verified with ls -ld "/proc/$$" (same PID in the current shell) and ls -ld /proc/self (differing PIDs each time).

cat /proc/self/limits would show the limits of the process spawned to run cat. cat /proc/$$/limits would show the limits of the shell process.

Yes, I understand. I pointed out because this comment "this command is spawned into a new process" could confuse readers.
